# Add a keyboard shortcut (hotkey) to Finder to copy path and open in QuickTime

Tags: keyboard, finder, shortcut-menu

I'm looking to build a script which does 2 things:

1. Copy the full path of a file in Finder to the clipboard (currently you have to right-click a file to open the context menu, and then hold down the Option key so that the Copy action changes to Copy Path, then click it)
2. Open in QuickTime. This is not the same as Open, because I want to support cases where QuickTime is not the default application for video files.

I would preferably like this all wrapped as a hotkey or combined into a single context menu item, preferably not under "Services".

Please note: I have a disability in both arms which means that right-clicking and moving the mouse around takes longer for me than most people!

Thank you

Comment: An Automator Action as a Service is precisely how you achieve this. Right-click menu items are not hot-keyable directly, they must appear in a top menu somewhere. You don't need to specifically capture the path to do this, you can send the selected file directly to QuickTime Player.